# How do I call a dependent library function from an sbt task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a CLI tool written in Java which can modify some source with the added params.  For example, it can rename an enum value across a whole project.

I want to write an sbt task that can run this tool from my project dir with the given params, like `sbt 'enums -rename A B'`.  My tool can be injected to the project through the sbt dependencies.

I skimmed through the book [sbt in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/sbt-in-action) looking for an answer, but those examples are not this specific.

My build.sbt (far from working):

```
name := """toolTestWithActivator"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Local Repository" at "file://C:/Users/torcsi/.ivy2/local"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "tool" % "tool_2.11" % "1.0",
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    cache,
    javaWs
)

val mytool = taskKey[String]("mytool")
mytool := {
    com.my.tool.Main
}
```

Can sbt handle this type of task/dependency structure, or do I need to do this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT is recursive: it compiles .sbt files and .scala files under the project folder and use those to execute your build (in fact you can see sbt as a library that helps you producing builds).

So, as you need your library to define a task, that one is a dependency of your build.sbt file (and not a dependency of your project).

To declare that the build.sbt file depends on your library, just create a ".sbt" file in the project folder; example:

**project/dependencies.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "tool" %% "tool" % "1.0"
```

and in **build.sbt** add:

```
val mytool = taskKey[Unit]("mytool")
mytool := {
    com.my.tool.main(Array())
}
```

*Some comments:*

- be careful with the scala version used: as sbt 0.13 is compiled with scala 2.10; your library should also be compiled for scala 2.10 (the package should be `tools_2.10` ). And the new sbt 1.0 is compiled with scala 2.12.
- I used the `%%` notation, so that sbt adds by itself the expected scala version.
- I supposed your cli tool defines a classic java main method (or the scala equivalent). So, the argument should be an `Array` of `String` (here an empty one) and it returns `Unit` (void in java).

Some reference to understand the solution:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Organizing-Build.html

Comment: I will try this, but I think this will work as I imagined.